# Create new column based on conditions in other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two input dataframes I'm attempting to use to create a column in another dataframe (target column = 'Country' in df1). The issue is that one of the input dataframes (i.e., df2) has fewer rows than my target dataframe (i.e., df1). I want to iterate through all possible countries in df2 but when that is exhausted (i.e., after 'KOR'), I want the column to revert to df3 and return the countries starting from the beginning, hence the target result in `df1['Country']`.

I had believed I found a way of doing this using `numpy.where`, but I ended up with 'ESP' instead of 'US' when reverting to df3 and that's not my objective.

Also, these are just examples, the actual dataframes in question are much larger.

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
    import pandas as pd

    data1 = {'Name': ['tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
             'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18],
             'Country': ['IND', 'KOR', 'US', 'UK']}
    
    data2 = {'Country2': ['IND', 'KOR']}
    
    data3 = {'Country': ['US', 'UK', 'ESP', 'MEX']}

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

EDIT: The easiest way I can think of to more clearly explain my goal is to utilize excel, where df1 begins in A1, df2 begins in E1, and df3 begins in H1. In that case, the formula in C1 (the beginning of the country column in df1) would be something like =IF(LEN(E1)>0,E1,H1). If i pull that formula down the cells, i'd basically have something similar to "if df2 has a country available, provide the name of that country, else, revert to the beginning of df3 and provide the country (beginning at the start of the list)"

Comment: can you elaborate on your expected output?

Comment: Please write out, _concretely_, what your expected output is.

Comment: Something like `df1['Country'] = pd.concat([df2['Country2'], df3['Country']], ignore_index=True).iloc[0:df1.shape[0]]`?

Comment: Thanks so much Michael this appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. Would you mind explaining what's going on in the formula?

Comment: @bigjdawg43 Take the country columns of "df2" and "df3", `concat`enate them to a longer column, take so much items from the beginning as "df1" has rows and set the result as country column of "df1".

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. Am i able to accept your comment as an answer? I don't see a way to do that.